# What is the best way to implement a blog on a website that uses the Symfony framework?

Tags: wordpress, symfony, blogs

Our company website was built using the Symfony framework. We want to add a blog to it in a subdirectory (so the website will be www.ourwebsite.com/blog). What is the easiest way to do this?

Ideally, I would like to use WordPress as it is what I am most experienced in, but switching the entire site over to WordPress is not an option. One option is to create a subdomain for the blog (blog.ourwebsite.com) but we are investing a large amount of money into SEO and our website already has decent rankings. We would like to use a blog to further increase the rankings of our website, and I feel that having it in a subdomain would slow us down from reaching our goals based on the limited amount of research I've done.

Comment: create a subdomain and keep wordpress on that subdomain, it is the easiest thing to do ( like blog.mycompany.com ), using ../path may lead to errors if you are running symfony on the same domain. I dont think there is a hug penalty in using subdomain , to the contrary

Answer (score 2):

I would solve this at the webserver level. Suppose the Symfony app lives at `/var/www/example.com` and the Wordpress blog at `/var/www/blog.example.com`.

For Apache, something like this should do:

```
<VirtualHost example.com:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
    ServerName example.com

    <Directory /var/www/example.com>
        # Your Symfony config here
    </Directory>

    Alias /blog /var/www/blog.example.com

    <Directory /var/www/blog.example.com>
        # Your Wordpress config here
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

See [Alias directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) for details. If you get the idea, it should be straightfoward to adapt this to other webservers, such as Nginx, if you're not using Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just go with: [symblog.co.uk](http://symblog.co.uk/) if you are willing to go a little more into the code.