# Symfony2 with Wordpress - How to redirect to /blog subfolder with htaccess?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, symfony

I have simmilar question to this one: [What is the best way to implement a blog on a website that uses the Symfony framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14609767/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-a-blog-on-a-website-that-uses-the-symfony-fram), I have a website running on Symfony2 and I want to have a blog (wordpress) in /blog but I don't have access to VirtualHosts, how I can do this with htaccess?

Comment: So what exactly do you want? you want `http://www.example.com` to redirect to `http://www.example.com/blog`?

Comment: I want to have Symfony website on http://www.example.com and Wordpress blog on http://www.example.com/blog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the accepted answer here - [Symfony Ignore Directory in web/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7728265/symfony-ignore-directory-in-web)

Quote:

> Ok. I figured it out. The .htaccess of the sub directory also needs to
>   be modified.
>
> In `web/.htaccess` use:
>
> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> ```
>
> In the sub directory, `web/other_app/.htaccess` use:
>
> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteBase /
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /other_app/index.php [QSA,L]
> ```
>
> This will work for wordpress and most any other php app that you want
>   to run on a symfony site, but don't want to deal with trying to hack
>   it into the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
..... 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    # wordpress rules 
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ blog/$1 [PT,L]

    # symfony rules 
    DirectoryIndex app.php
    .....
```